# Spherical coordinates of two Sphere Equations (bounds for integral)

Tags: calculus, multiple-integral, spherical-coordinates

I'm given two spheres; $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=2$. I'm trying to convert from rectangular to spherical coordinates to integrate the region between the two spheres, and my bounds so far are $1\leqslant p \leqslant 2$, $0\leqslant \theta \leqslant 2\pi$, and $0\leqslant\phi\leqslant \pi/2$. When I plug these in and integrate I'm getting the wrong answer, and I checked that my integration was correct so it must be an issue with the bounds.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $\phi$ should be between $0$ and $\pi$ and $\rho$ should be between $1$ and $\sqrt2$. If that doesn't solve it then show your work for us to check for other mistakes.

Comment: ϕ was indeed incorrect, but I think ρ was correct, because upon integrating I received a whacky answer with a root 2 cubed, but upon integrating with a bound of 2 rather than √2, I got 28pi/3, which is the difference between the volume of the two spheres.

Comment: Figured out what was wrong, I forgot that the first equation meant the radius of the sphere was root 2, not 2.